# Python: slice yearly data between February and June with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, slice

I have a dataset with 10 years of data from 2000 to 2010. I have the initial datetime on 2000-01-01, with data resampled to daily. I also have a weekly counter for when I apply the `slice()` function, I will only ask for week 5 to week 21 (February 1 to May 30).

I am a little stuck with how I can slice it every year, does it involve a loop or is there a timeseries function in python that will know to slice for a specific period in every year? Below is the code I have so far, I had a for loop that was supposed to `slice(5, 21)` but that didn't work.

Any suggestions how might I get this to work?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

initial_datetime = pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01")

# Read the file
df = pd.read_csv("D:/tseries.csv")

# Convert seconds to datetime
df["Time"] = df["Time"].map(lambda dt: initial_datetime+timedelta(seconds=dt))
    
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Time"]))
resampling_period = "24H"
df = df.resample(resampling_period).mean().interpolate()
df["Week"] = df.index.map(lambda dt: dt.week)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice using `loc`:

`df.loc[df.Week.isin(range(5,22))]`

If you want separate calculations per year (f.e. mean), you can use `groupby`:

```
subset = df.loc[df.Week.isin(range(5,22))]
subset.groupby(subset.index.year).mean()
```